# XUL: How to include and extend another .xul file?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I like to create a window by extending the *basic* Firefox window which is defined in chrome://browser/content/browser.xul as the top level element (is not overlay).

My question is about branching/forking from basic window definition before any modification applied to it by other extension and is *not* about how to apply overlay or modification to what user see as main FF window.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your question is still about overlays. Your overlay should go like this:</strike>

```
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <window id="main-window">
        <commandset id="my-commands">
            ...
        </commandset>
    </window>
</overlay>
```

<strike>This example will add a `<commandset>` element to the root of the browser window (which happens to be a `<window>` element with ID `main-window`).</strike>

**Edit**: It appears that the question wasn't about adding elements on the top level but rather about making a fork of an existing XUL document. You can create an alias by adding an `override` directive to your chrome.manifest:

```
override chrome://myextension/content/browser.xul chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
```

Now you can apply an overlay to the alias ony:

```
overlay chrome://myextension/content/browser.xul chrome://myextension/content/browserOverlay.xul
```

Overlays apply to URLs which makes this possible. Now you can open `chrome://myextension/content/browser.xul` in a new window and it should be the browser window but with your overlay applied. Please note that this approach has limitations, e.g. extensions overlaying the browser window will have no effect on your window (their overlays only apply to the original browser window URL).

Comment: I saved this as my.xul and then opend it using chrome://... but it shows nothing. View source only shows my.xul content, browser.xul contents are not merged.

Comment: I have stated in my question that I don't need to apply any change to browser.xul which is viewed to user as FF window but create another window forking from *basic* FF window (browser.xul without merging with other addon overlays).

Comment: Oh my, you couldn't have phrased it more confusing... To create a "fork" of the Firefox window add this to your chrome.manifest:

    `override chrome://myextension/content/browser.xul chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`

Now apply the overlay only to your "forked" version:

    `overlay chrome://myextension/content/browser.xul chrome://myextension/content/browserOverlay.xul`

That's it, now you can open `chrome://myextension/content/browser.xul` in a new window.

Comment: Should I expect `override` to merge basic FF browser.xul with my browser.xul?

Comment: By the way whats the problem with [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29) or [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29)?

Comment: There is no problem with the word fork - it simply doesn't quite apply here. `override` will create a new alias for the regular browser.xul document. Overlays apply by URL which is why you can have your overlay apply to the alias but not to the original browser window.

Comment: Please make an edit to your answer so that I can remove my down vote (my vote is locked).

Comment: I've done that now. Please edit your question as well to include the word "fork" or something along the lines, I will remove my down vote as well then.